# Android Speech Recognizer on different Devices

Tags: android, speech-recognition, audio-recording, speech-to-text

After testing multiple different approaches of speech to text, i finally come to conclusion that the issue is from my specific device the code works fine on one device Android 5 while i keep receiving error on the other one which run Android 6

The second device is Chinese device using a custom sdk i'm wondering if there is a specific service that is needed in Android it self in order to enable the Speech Recognizer considering that i did install google voice app and did enable it using adb and same issue keep showing up

is there a way or Debugging Strategy should i use to find the source of this issue.

```
public class STT extends AppCompatActivity implements RecognitionListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//android view initialization removed

    String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};
    if(!Function.hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_PERMISSION_KEY);
    }


    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
    recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
            "en");
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
            this.getPackageName());
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);

    /*
    Minimum time to listen in millis. Here 5 seconds
     */
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 5000);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.DICTATION_MODE", true);




    recordbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View p1)
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
            recordbtn.setEnabled(false);

            /*To stop listening
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                speech.stopListening();
                recordbtn.setEnabled(true);
             */
        }


    });



}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (speech != null) {
        speech.destroy();
        Log.d("Log", "destroy");
    }

}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    Log.d("Log", "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
    Log.d("Log", "onBufferReceived: " + buffer);
}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    Log.d("Log", "onEndOfSpeech");
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    recordbtn.setEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onError(int errorCode) {
    String errorMessage = getErrorText(errorCode);
    Log.d("Log", "FAILED " + errorMessage);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    returnedText.setText(errorMessage);
    recordbtn.setEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    Log.d("Log", "onEvent");
}

 @Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.d("Log", "onPartialResults");

    ArrayList<String> matches = arg0.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    String text = "";
    /* To get all close matchs
    for (String result : matches)
    {
        text += result + "\n";
    }
    */
    text = matches.get(0); //  Remove this line while uncommenting above    codes


    returnedText.setText(text);
}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.d("Log", "onReadyForSpeech");
}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    Log.d("Log", "onResults");

}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
    Log.d("Log", "onRmsChanged: " + rmsdB);
    progressBar.setProgress((int) rmsdB);

}


public static String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
    String message;
    switch (errorCode) {
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
            message = "Audio recording error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
            message = "Client side error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
            message = "Insufficient permissions";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
            message = "Network error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
            message = "Network timeout";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
            message = "No match";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
            message = "RecognitionService busy";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
            message = "error from server";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
            message = "No speech input";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
            break;
    }
    return message;
}
}
class Function {

public static  boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a dependency on the "Google" app (which has the ID `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox`):
you could check if the device has it installed, and if not, install it from Google's Play Store.

> ...
>   is there a way or Debugging Strategy should i use to find the source of this issue.

Is there no error message in the `LogCat` output?

Comment: i did install google service and enable it from adb using: (adb shell==>su==>pm enable com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox Got Package com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox new state: enabled ) still same the issue, i got Error Code 3 (Recording error) i believe the mic is occupied by another package which i cannot identify